# Generate number of Edit Text by storing andretrieve each value

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to generate number of EditText column wise to store and retrieve each value .

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: what efforts you have made for it?!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you to resolve your problem.

```
EditText[] etxt = new EditText[Size];
EditText et;

//Generate and set values
for(int i=0;i<Size;i++)
{
  et = new EditText(this);
  et.setText(""+i)
  et.setId(i);

  etxt[i] =  et;

  //Add item to your view
  //YourView.addView(etxt[i]);
}

Now you need to add to your View

//Get values
for(int s=0;s<etxt.lenght;s++)
{
  etxt[s] =  et;
  Log.i("Test","Value: "+etxt[i].getText().toString());
}
```